# C++: cout выводит преобразованые в строку числа больше 256

Tags: c++, строки, консоль

У меня проблема cout не хочет выводить числа больше чем 256 символов на экран. Моя программа создаёт массив из случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне. После этого выводит его на экран. Кроме этого вычисляет самый большой и самый маленький его элемент. Программа распознает число т.к выводит как максимальные числа больше 256, но на экране их не видно. Буду рад любой помощи.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>
 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int size = 20;  
    int array[size];
    srand(time(NULL));
    string random_arr = "";
    int min_value = 0;
    int max_value = 1000;
    int random_num;
//заполняем массив случайными числами
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    random_num = min_value + rand() % (max_value-min_value+1);
    array[i]=random_num;
    random_arr[i] += random_num;
}
// выводим массив на экран  
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
//ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!
    cout<<"["<<to_string(random_arr[i])<<"]"; 
// ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!
}
int max_element;
string array_str;
//находим наименьший элемент массива
int min_element = INT_MAX;
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    if(array[i] < min_element)
    {
    min_element = array[i];
    }
}
cout<<"\nМинимальный элемент: "<<min_element;
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    if(array[i] > max_element)
    {
    max_element = array[i];
    }
}
cout<<"\nМаксимальный элемент: "<<max_element;
```

}

Comment: Интересно, чего вы ждете от выражения `random_arr[i] += random_num;`? Особенно если учесть, что `random_arr` — это пустая строка?

Comment: Я поправил random_arr[i] на random_arr но от этого ничего не меняется программа все равно выводит числа не больше 256.  В random_arr я записываю элементы массива как строку чтобы вывести на экран.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Вы не записываете числа в строку. Запись чисел в строку как-то так `random_arr += string(" ") + to_string(array[i]);`

Comment: @Максим Вы в курсе, что типы данных random_arr и random_num разные?

Comment: DmitryK я сделал как вы показали, но к сожалению программа теперь выводит числа от 1 до 58

Comment: Опишите, **что вы хотите** от вашей программы, тогда будет о чем говорить. Только *точное, однозначное* задание.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь в комментарий все не влезет, поэтому оформлю как ответ.
У Вас есть несколько ошибок.

1. Вот этот код должен приводить к ошибки компиляции:

   int size = 20;
   int array[size];

т.к. при объявлении массива в квадратных скобках должна быть константа, т.е. нужно заменить на const `int size = 20`.

2. Как уже писали в комментариях, `random_arr` - это строка, `random_num` переменная типа int (т.е. целое число) и ее перед присвоением `random_arr` необходимо привести к строке, например, как написано в комментариях, используя функцию `to_string`. Так же, такая запись `random_arr[i]` означает, что вы обращаетесь к конкретному элементу этой строки, что в данном случае не нужно, а добавление новой подстроки в `random_arr` можно сделать следующим образом: `random_arr += ("[" + to_string(random_num)+"]");`. И соответственно цикл, который у Вас вызывает проблему заменяется всего одной строкой `cout << random_arr`. Или можно избавиться от строки `random_arr` сразу выводить элементы массива. Тогда ваш проблемный цикл будет выглядеть так:

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
   cout<<"["<<array[i]<<"]";
   }
3. И, вроде, последнее - переменная `int max_element` у Вас не инициализирована, а значит строка `if(array[i] > max_element)` также приведет к ошибке компиляции.

Comment: Действительно, так писать не стоит, но уточню, что первый код приводит к CE только при `-pedantic-errors`, а третий - UB, что обычно не приводит к CE при использовании в неконстантном выражении.